# Capacitor 250V DC

Tags: capacitive

I have 0.22uF 250V DC MLCC SMD capacitor.
Can I use it for 230V AC main as capacitive power supply?

Your suggestion will be helpful for me.

Comment: 230V AC has a peak voltage of 325V. Also take into account the variance in your mains voltage - assuming that it could be 10% higher is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

No, unless the datasheet of the capacitor allows it.

Based on voltage DC specs this capacitor is not suitable.